# SwitchPreferenceCompat selected/clicked color

Tags: android, android-support-library

I recently ported an old settings page to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` - it's very simple and only has some SwitchPreferenceCompat settings on the UI with a white background.

When you click on the preference to change it, the highlight colors look awful. The screenshot below is what it looks like while clicking and holding.

[image]

How do I change the highlight colors?

Here's my current preferenceTheme:

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```